# Efficiently managing Data Storage Limit: EmailMessage

Tags: data-storage, email2case, emailmessage, archive

we currently use the On Demand Email To Case functionality via different routing addresses. I have switched off the option "Save Headers" on the Email To Case routing addresses to reduce the size of the email.

The issue we are having is we are very very close to the Data Storage limit!! Obviously I've had a quote for more storage but wanted other options.

We have a massive amount of file storage and I have thought about creating a PDF version of the EmailMessage record and storing them as attachments against the Case. I used a tool from "Cumulusforce" which almost did the job, however if there are several hundred EmailMessages per case it creates several hundred attachments with a not very meaningful name!

Deleting the records is probably the least favorable option as they’d need to be stored and be readily available to be viewed from within Salesforce, although I could delete records greater than 3 years old.

Are there any tools on the market which will aid us?

Comment: are you also capturing Tasks (ActivityHistory) with a copy of the `EmailMessage`; that could be another place to look for savings

Comment: No, we are not creating any ActivityHistory,